# Unable to setup website created using Lemoon template in VS 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, lemoon

This is what I've done/tried:
1. Downloaded the "Lemoon Web Application" template from Visual Studio extension manager
2. Created a new project (File->New Project) using this template
3. Compiled the code
5. Ran the set by using CTRL + F5

I get as fat as the setup screen as shown on the [Lemoon.com site](http://www.lemoon.com/developers/getting-started/installation-and-setup). After entering all information, when I click setup, I see this message:

> An error occurred during setup: Failed to register lemoon.
>   This is what i see in the logfile under App_Data\Logs folder:
>   ========================================================================== 2013-07-16 12:04:03.7855|INFO|Mindroute.Core.BootStrapper|Starting up
>   ========================================================================== 2013-07-16 12:04:04.8656|INFO|Mindroute.Core.BootStrapper|Startup
>   completed in 1076ms 2013-07-16
>   12:04:04.8866|INFO|Mindroute.Lemoon.Services.SetupService|Setup
>   started 2013-07-16
>   12:04:07.8009|INFO|Mindroute.Core.Services.LicenseService|Requesting
>   new license 2013-07-16
>   12:04:09.9891|ERROR|Mindroute.Core.Services.LicenseService|License
>   request failed. System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the
>   remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection
>   could be made because the target machine actively refused it
>   91.189.44.135:80    at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)    at
>   System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure,
>   Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address,
>   ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception&
>   exception)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
>   System.Net.WebClient.DownloadDataInternal(Uri address, WebRequest&
>   request)    at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadString(Uri address)    at
>   System.Net.WebClient.DownloadString(String address)    at
>   Mindroute.Core.Services.LicenseService.Set(String licenseKey, Boolean
>   register) 2013-07-16
>   12:04:10.2912|INFO|Mindroute.Core.Services.LicenseService|License
>   request failed 2013-07-16
>   12:04:10.3472|FATAL|Mindroute.Lemoon.Services.SetupService|Setup
>   failed.

I can see that there are tables created in the database configured in Web.Config. What am I missing? What license request is it trying to send?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lemoon needs to connect with our licensing server and create a license key.

Is your server able to reach the internet? If not, install it on a computer with internet access and re-do the startup, or if it can, try doing it again to see if it was a temporary connection problem.

Comment: I'm actually trying to do this on my work-PC which is behind a proxy. Are there any proxy settings i need to make?

Comment: Btw, I just retried and still get the same message in logs: License request failed. What URL is the license request going to?

Comment: The URL is "license.lemoon.com".
Have you edited the web.config file for proxy configuration? See more here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kd3cf2ex.aspx

Comment: That was it! after adding the following section under <system.net>,       <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true">
      <proxy proxyaddress="<myproxy>:<port>" />
    </defaultProxy>                                                my website is up and running! :) Thanks a ton!